# How can a peer request another peer to invoke a function from his private contract

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-invocation, quorum

I build a permissioned network using Quorum,

I have a peerA which has a private smart contract, another peerB that cannot invoke functions of the smart contract as it is private

So, can peerB send transaction to peerA to request it to invoke a function from his private contract.

Answer (score 1):

Not through a txn on the chain. If a private contract is defined between party A and B, and C needs to execute a call then this would have to be handled with an off chain call in some way, for example through an API offered by A or B.

Comment: Thx fixaoind for the response

Comment: Can I define another contract X for the peer A that is not private and that contains a function that calls the function in his private contract Y? 
Then, B can invoke the function in contract X in order to invoke the function in contract Y.
 It that possible and what could be the pros and the cons of such solution ?

Comment: Hi, at the moment, the state model only permits reading from public contracts in a private contract. Public contracts cannot access contents of the private state at all.

Comment: Hi fixanoid, many thx for your help, just I want to be sure about one thing. This is even if the private and the public contract are deployed by the same node? In fact here https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/357 I found that it is possible: "On node 1 i can properly add SimpleStorage-contract to StorageContainer and also i can get private value 45 from it. On node 7 or 4 i get value 0. So all works properly."